# How to use Telnet with Personal Hotspot (tethering)?

Tags: iphone, wifi, ping, tethering

I got the Personal Hotspot working great, with both USB and WiFi (on different computers/devices).

However, I am not able to ping or telnet the other computer. Both computers can ping the iPhone (default gateway). I found the other computers IP through ifconfig and ipconfig.

Is there a limitation on what kind of traffic can go through a Personal Hotspot? Where can I find support or documentation? (I searched Google and Apple support). Are there any settings or configuration files?

Is there another solution, such as using my own WiFi or wired router for local traffic and the iPhone for internet?

Using version 4.3.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need ping at all? Can the computers connect via ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found one solution that works great.

Since the connection between the computers was originally wired with a router, I plugged them both into the router.

Then I removed the default gateway settings from the ***wired*** connection. This prevents them from going to the internet via the wired connection.

But, they are both connected to iPhone by wireless or USB (a separate wired connection), so they go to the internet through iPhone. The first time it takes the computer about 10 seconds to figure this out.

The caveat is that you need 2 interfaces for each device and a way to connect separate from iPhone.